# Discounted bundled product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cart, bundled-product

I need a bundle product that works as follows:

The bundle together is €650,- with Item 1 being €500,- and Item 2 being €150 ( Discounted, because it's bundled. )

Without the bundle, Item 2 would be €200,-.

If I remove Item 1 from my cart, I now have the option to have the Item 2 for cheaper than it should be. *This should not happen*.

Is there any reliable solution to this? I've been thinking about detecting if it's bundled, and cheaper if bundled(?) and remove that corresponding item from the cart aswell, is there any tips on how I would go about and do that?

I'm currently using Simple Bundle extension, this does what we need but it doesn't allow my question here,  If there is a functioning extension that does what I mentioned, please refer me to that, I can't find one myself so I've been trying to go about it another way.

Comment: Can't you simply use a Shopping Cart Price Rule? http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide-Jan-29/content/marketing/price-rules-shopping-cart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an extension. It sounds like you are using grouped products, because with bundles you can *not* remove simple items separately.

If you configure the bundle product correctly, it fits exactly your needs:

- option 1: type checkbox, required

  - selection 1.1 "Item 1", fixed qty 1
- option 2: type checkbox, required

  - selection 1.1 "Item 2", fixed qty 1
- bundle price type: fixed, 650 €

(options with type "checkbox" and "required" will show up without any input field and are always part of the bundle, i.e. they cannot be removed)

Comment: I'm sorry, I've seen the edits and it's clear how I've been unclear, currently I use the extension Simple Bundle, which does the bundling.

Comment: No problem, but did I understand you correct?

Comment: It would be, but our customer don't work with bundles like that basically, they don't have bundles currently we use the extension Simple Bundle, which does the bundling, they have products in the shop, they want to make bundles of, technical my collegue says it's efficient as is, just this one issue is what stops us. Basically they want a "Buy this, get x" possibilitie(s). I hope I'm clear.

Comment: "they have products in the shop, they want to make bundles of" - so what's stopping them from creating a bundled product?

Comment: I'm not deep into the project/customer, but I've understood there was a reason and they went with the extension which does almost exactly what they want and makes is easier for them with the import etc, I assume. I can't get clarification at the moment, but I will try to get that asap.

Comment: Then I can't help you any further. Extensions that do "almost" what you want are often a bad idea.

Comment: Oké that's too bad. So your advice is to make actual bundled products? The customer has literally only simple products in the import, and making it different would be troublesome for them on their part, thus the reason we're using this extension. Thanks for taking the time, I hope someone cuold potentially answer this question, else I'll mark it for you.

Comment: I have marked this answer as the correct one, as what was wanted would be possible this way, but because of the way our customer works with literally only simple products, and no actual bundles. We've gone with a different route, this however, does what I asked ( Remove both items from cart )